# How to handle bash sort of for tie conditions

Tags: bash, sorting

I'd like to sort a file with name and count. How can I sort it based on the count for descending order and when it meet a tie, sort the name by ascending order?

for example:

```
a 31
b 82
d 21
l 31
o 21
```

to

```
b 82    
a 31
l 31
d 21
o 21
```

I tried to use `sort -k 2r -n -t $'\t' output -o output` but it doesn't not work.
Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure how much you've (over-)simplified your data for asking on SO, but for the data shown, you wouldn't need to specify the separator — `sort` splits on white space — blanks and tabs — by default.  If you actually have space-separated words in column 1 and a tab separating that from the number in column 2, then you'd need the `-t` option.  It isn't a big deal at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k2rn -k1 file

b 82
a 31
l 31
d 21
o 21
```

**`sort` options:**

```
-t $'\t'    # use tab as field delimiter 
-k2rn       # first sort on reverse numeric order on field2
-k1         # then sort on natural (alphabetic) order of field1
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort -k2,2nr -k1,1d /tmp/sort.txt`

EDIT: You can have multiple -k options. `d` option is for a dictionary order of first column (and second `-k` option). It can be skipped:

`sort -k2,2nr -k1,1 /tmp/sort.txt`

Even more defaults can be used:

`sort -k2nr -k1 /tmp/sort.txt`

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention what the `-d` does since it wasn't used in the question.  ([`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) says 'dictionary order'.)